# Jquery Ui Combobox and onchange on all and setval

Tags: jquery-ui, combobox

I have a web project with many selects that are already programmed like a chained selects. I want to turn them all to comboboxes and have 2 main issues. how to make that onchange of select will be also transfered automatically to onchange of combobox and  when i have set value operation to given select which is transfered to be a combobox , all this operations will wark also without extrea recoding...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can see this this may help you adding change event
http://jsfiddle.net/mhameen/jBqkp/